# IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol while running yum command

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, redhat, yum, linux-mint

When I try to turn any yum command I get the follwing message. I disabled and enabled SSL before this error occurred. As the system said RHNS-CA-CERT has expired, I removed the certificate and downloaded it using wget command. Then I tried to update the certificate using the yum command and that's where the problem started.

Here's the error message:

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 285, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 105, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 228, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 891, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 362, in _getConfig
    self.plugins.run('init')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 184, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/share/yum-plugins/rhnplugin.py", line 118, in init_hook
    login_info = up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 219, in getLoginInfo
    login(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 170, in login
    server = rhnserver.RhnServer(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rhnserver.py", line 154, in __init__
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 160, in getServer
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhn/rpclib.py", line 169, in __init__
    self._reset_host_handler_and_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhn/rpclib.py", line 315, in _reset_host_handler_and_type
    raise IOError, "unsupported XML-RPC protocol"
IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol
```

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault.com with this one.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my guess is you are running against RHN Classic (rhn.redhat.com). There were erratum fixing this expired certificate and here comes relevant knowleadge base article:

System connection to RHN fails with "The certificate is expired, or certificate verify failed" errors
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/353033

Traceback with `IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol` leads me to guess that you have incorrect `serverURL` in `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`. It should look like this:

```
serverURL=https://xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC
```